# Where clause in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The model for my Resource class is as follows:

```
class Resource(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    availability = ndb.StructuredProperty(Availability, repeated=True)
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    owner = ndb.StringProperty()
    id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    lastReservedTime = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
    startString = ndb.StringProperty()
    endString = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I want to extract records where the owner is equal to a certain string.
I have tried the below query. It does not give an error but does not return any result either.

```
Resource.query(Resource.owner== 'abc@xyz.com').fetch()
```

As per my understanding if a column has duplicate values it shouldn't be indexed and that is why owner is not indexed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can someone help me figure out how to achieve a where clause kind of functionality?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you have `Resource` entities whose owner property is equal to `'abc@xyz.com'`?  As far as I can tell, this looks correct to me.

Comment: @mgilson : Hey! Yes I am sure that there are records which should match the value. In fact the only records that are in my datastore are the ones with this owner and when I extract all records from the DS(like a select * statement) I am able to retrieve all of them correctly.

Comment: try `Resource.gql("WHERE owner = :1", 'abc@xyz.com').fetch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this. It worked first time. Either you have no Resource entities with an owner of "abc@xyz.com", or the owner property was not indexed when the entities were put (which can happen if you had indexed=False at the time the entities were put).

My test:

```
Resource(id='1', owner='abc@xyz.com').put()
Resource(id='2', owner='abc@xyz.com').put()
resources = Resource.query(Resource.owner == 'abc@xyz.com').fetch()
assert len(resources) == 2
```

Also, your comment:

> As per my understanding if a column has duplicate values it shouldn't
>   be indexed and that is why owner is not indexed. Please correct me if
>   I am wrong.

Your wrong!

Firstly, there is no concept of a 'column' in a datastore model, so I will I assume you mean '[Property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties)'.

Next, to clarify what you mean by "if a <strike>column</strike> property has duplicate values":

- I assume you mean 'multiple entities created from the same model with the same value for a specific property', in your case 'owner'. This has no effect on indexing, each entity will be indexed as expected.
- Or maybe you mean 'a single entity with a property that allows multiple values (ie a list)', which also does not prevent indexing. In this case, the entity will be indexed multiple times, once for each item in the list.

To further elaborate, most properties (ie ones that accept primitive types such as string, int, float etc) are indexed automatically, unless you add the attribute `indexed=False` to the Property constructor. In fact, the only time you really need to worry about indexing is when you need to perform more complex queries, which involve querying against more that 1 property (and even then, by default, the app engine dev server will auto create the indexes for you in your local index.yaml file), or using inequality filters.

Please [read](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) [the](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig) for more detail.

Hope this helps!